# For Loops and jquery music player

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio-player

I am currently having issues with using a for loop to make a track in a JQuery web player go back 10 seconds

```
$("#bck").click(function(){
$("#player").trigger("pause");  
    for (i=1; i == 10; i++){
        if($("#player").prop("currentTime") !=0)
        {
            $("#player").prop("currentTime", $("#player").prop("currentTime") -= 1);
        }
    }
    $("#player").trigger("play");
})
```

Also, is there a JQuery property for the length of the song so i can just simply replace the `!=0` with whatever the length is, in seconds

Comment: Why do you need the for loop at all?

Comment: i just didn't want it to try going before the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only looping to check when the beginning of the track is reached is foolish and not necessary. You could use the `Math.max` function to ensure value is 0 or above:

```
var currentTime = $("#player").prop("currentTime");
var newTime = Math.max(currentTime - 10, 0);
```

Comment: What's the link. Don't see much there. My suggestion to replace the for loop strategy to find result for x - 10 which should be greater than zero even if x is less than 10 is definitely correct.

Comment: it's a codio url but   `var currentTime = $("#player").prop("currentTime");
var newTime = Math.max(currentTime - 10, 0);
    $("#player").prop("currentTime", newTime);`

Comment: Is `prop()` returning integer? If not wrap that into `parseInt()` like `var currentTime = parseInt($("#player").prop("currentTime"))`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it returns an integer

Comment: It _should_ fix. Don't see why not. Problem lies somewhere else then. Create a JSFiddle if you can. Pretty sure is not necessarily proof. Debug, check, use `console.log()` to see values, types.

Answer (score 0):

ALL WORKS WITH AUDIO OR VIDEO

**Go back 10 sec Ex**

```
var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
audio.currentTime -= 10;
```

**Duration Ex.**

```
alert(audio.duration);
```

**Loop Ex**

```
audio.loop = true;
```